# Crontab unable to execute PHP script. bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: php, linux, apache

Trying to use Crontab to execute commands at regular intervals. But crontab keeps giving the error:

> /bin/sh: /var/www/html/Scripts/lib/Tasks.php: /usr/bin/php^M: bad
>   interpreter: No such file or directory

Tasks.php:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
//scripts
?>
```

I feel like my Shebang is messed up. The main php file appears to be present in /usr/bin/php but I keep getting the error. I have been trying other shebangs from other posts but most of them are not using the combination of Centos6 php5 and apache. I just need to execute this php script every few min.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php file shebang operator will not work as per my understanding.

You can rewrite crontab as below:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/Scripts/lib/Tasks.php
```

You can change crontab frequency as per you need. Also please verify if php is at right place with below command:

```
which php
```

Thanks.

Comment: This resolved that issue however parse_ini_file(/Config/Config.ini): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in.

Comment: Please provide absolute path in parse_ini_file function from root folder or the folder relative to the file in which this code is written

Comment: I solved it already i was posting that there for anyone else experiencing issues. Thank you so much Ramdas.